# Can't use "Object" or "Objects" as entity in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, reserved-words

I'm not sure, but I think I'm having problems with my project because one entity has the name "Object", tried to change this to "Objects", nothing changes. Maybe it's a reserved word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Sep/msg02159.html) `Object` was an original root class for Objective-C which still exists somewhere in the class hierarchy so it wont be able to be used. I'm not sure about `Objects` but the obvious solution is to prefix your class names (which you should be doing anyway, but it's especially important for generic names like "Object")